# Problems reading from a file which multiple inputs have been saved to in a python program

Tags: python

For some reason my python program only writes the second to last item that has been saved to the file.
I do not understand why and would like some enlightening please.
This is my simplified chunk of program:

```
while True:
    file=open('emails.txt','w+')
    email=input('pls input your email adress: ')
    more=input('would you like more emails to be processed? ')
    if more == 'yes' or more == 'ye' or more == 'y' or more == 'yep' or more == 'Y':
        file.write(email)
        file.write('\n')
        continue

    elif more == 'no' or more == 'nah' or more == 'n' or more == 'N' or more == 'nope':
        file.close()
        print('this is the list of emails so far')
        file=open('emails.txt','r')
        print(file.read())
        exit()
```

Comment: Try moving `file=open('emails.txt','w+')` to before the `while` loop.

Comment: Try putting `file=open('emails.txt', 'w+')` outside for loop. Each iteration of while loop will overwrite that file. Or try `append` mode

Comment: Also, for your final email address, when you type it in and select no, it never reaches the `file.write()`. That's why the last one will never be written out

Comment: thanks for all your answers i realise my mistakes now! :)